# What's the difference between `;` and space when setting environment variable before running a command

Tags: bash, zsh, posix-compliant

I've been wondering what's the difference between the two:

- `CAROOT='certificates'; echo $CAROOT` - prints the value, uses `;` as separator between two commands
- `CAROOT='certificates' echo $CAROOT` - prints empty value.

I wonder why the former command works but the latter didn't?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [How do I set an environment variable on the command line and have it appear in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

The following command line and its output can help explain how it works.

```
$ LANG=C bash -c 'echo LANG=$LANG'; echo LANG=$LANG
LANG=C
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
```

`LANG=C` with only a space works only on the following command, after that the old LANG setting is used again.

But why does it print an empty value in your second case? I would explain it like this: The variable will be expanded by the shell directly. This is different from the case with `bash -c 'echo LANG=$LANG'`, where the variable is protected [by the quotes] at first, and will be expanded later, when the previous variable set command has already been processed.

---

The method with only a space, no semicolon is often used, when you want to change language temporarily, as in the following example where the heading is changed to the standard language (English).

```
$ df -h
Filsystem      Storlek Använt Ledigt Anv% Monterat på
udev               16G      0    16G   0% /dev
tmpfs             3,2G   1,6M   3,2G   1% /run
/dev/sda5          88G    32G    52G  39% /
tmpfs              16G      0    16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             5,0M   4,0K   5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs              16G      0    16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb7         3,5T   998G   2,4T  30% /media/multimed-2
tmpfs             3,2G    20K   3,2G   1% /run/user/1000

$ LANG=C df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3,2G  1,6M  3,2G   1% /run
/dev/sda5        88G   32G   52G  39% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb7       3,5T  998G  2,4T  30% /media/multimed-2
tmpfs           3,2G   20K  3,2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Setting a variable with only space before a command sets that variable to be only available in that command's scope/environment check `var='123' printenv var` … however with the `var='123' echo “$var”`, `$var` gets expanded by the running shell before the `echo` command is run and even before `var` itself is set … hence the empty string … i.e. expansion happens first … the `;` nests procedures in the order they will be executed and sets `var` in the environment of the running shell before the next procedure after `;` including the expansion of `$var` happens … hence its value is printed.

Comment: Yes, @Raffa, your explanation is good :-)

Comment: +1 and :-) … Couldn’t include these in the first comment due to darn character limit.